# Does increasing gain of an op-amp improve transient response speed?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Consider a simple op-amp in a feedback configuration. You can consider the op-amp to be dominant pole compensated and approximated as a first order system.

Let's say that the transient performance (mainly rise time) in response to an input step of the closed-loop system is too slow.

The first option I have is to increase the bandwidth (and drop the gain, maintaining a fixed GBW) and this will make the system faster.

My question is: **Will increasing the DC gain help the transient performance?** I know it will reduce the BW. But intuitively, it makes sense right, a large gain means the op-amp can react more aggressively in voltage levels to bring itself back to steady-state

Comment: It increases the slew rate up to the amplifier's slew rate but you won't hit your target output value any faster because it is higher too if you increase the gain.

Comment: @DKNguyen sorry, what do you mean that the target is higher too?

Comment: If my input is 1, what is the output if my gain is 5 vs 10? You might go twice as fast (up to the slew rate) but you also have twice as far to go

Comment: @DKNguyen ahh, makes sense now. So then, the only real option I have is to extend my BW, dropping the gain in the process. That will improve transient performance.

Comment: Yeah, but it can depend on the circuit. Sometimes the GBWP is not the bottleneck. For example, in transimpedance amplifiers, the input capacitance is often initially the weakest link and there are ways to deal with that.

Comment: I understand. And I suppose another downside is that if I extend the bandwidth and drop the gain, I will have higher DC offset issues with the lower gain?

Comment: No...the changes you listed tend to be if you change  to a higher speed opamp, not if you stick with the  same opamp.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. DC offset is based on the open loop gain of the op amp right which will be unchanged.

Comment: So what is the tradeoff of reduced gain in exchange for better BW?

Comment: You are losing the gain, silly.

Comment: Oops. Forgot the whole purpose of the op amp in the first place.

Comment: All clear now. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because although your output slope increases (up to the max slew rate) as you increase the closed-loop gain, so too does your output value. You might go twice as fast but you have twice as far to go.